# Git remote default branch won't change

Tags: git, github, branch

I am in a GitHub Classroom repository created by my school.

I have forked this repository but my problem is the first branch I pushed to the origin wasn't named `master` but let's say `MyBranch`. Then I have created more branches locally and pushed them to the origin and one of them was called `master` because I figured out I want to set my default branch to be `master`.

But now when I go to my forked repo, I go to settings, Branches and change default from `MyBranch` to `master`, it changes only in my forked repo, not in the classroom repo.

The reason might be that classrom repo has still `MyBranch` set as default as it shows every time when I open classroom repo, so its like "landing page" for my classroom repo, but there is no "Settings" option as in the forked repo, probably because I do not have rights to change it or I don't know. But anyways, what can I do to get rid of the unwanted branch and change `master` to be my `default` branch?

**EDIT:**

I had to contact owner/administrator of the school repo to change my default branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of your remote `MyBranch` use:

```
git push origin --delete MyBranch
```

Or if you want the changes done in `MyBranch`, you can revers merge `MyBranch` to your `master` branch and get rid of the `MyBranch`.

Go to your `master` branch:

```
git merge MyBranch
git push origin --delete MyBranch
```

Comment: I get error when I want to delete `Mybranch` because its set to default in my classroom repo. `To https://github.com.....
 ! [remote rejected] MyBranch (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/MyBranch)
error: failed to push some refs to `

Comment: Try: https://superuser.com/questions/748058/how-do-i-delete-origin-master-in-git/749412#749412